# Class 'Silex\Application' not found

Tags: php, silex

I’ve done with google sign-up, I want to ask regarding google `token_id` authentication. Google issues a `token-id` to every user which changes on every sign-in, I am getting that token-id when the user sign-in, I want to authenticate that token-id from google to verify if the sign-in was original or fake. I am using this php api provided by google, but it is continuously giving this error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Silex\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\gplus-verifytoken-php-master\verify.php:23
>
> Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\gplus-verifytoken-php-master\verify.php on line 23

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

const CLIENT_ID = 'xyz';   
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'xyz';
const APPLICATION_NAME = "xyz";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__,
));
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

// Initialize a session for the current user, and render index.html.
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html', array(
        'CLIENT_ID' => CLIENT_ID,
        'APPLICATION_NAME' => APPLICATION_NAME
    ));
});

// Verify an ID Token or an Access Token.
// Example URI: /verify?id_token=...&access_token=...
$app->post('/verify', function (Request $request) use($app, $client) {

    $id_token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImE0MzY0YjVmYjliODYxYzNhYTRkYTg5NWExMjk5NzZjMjgyZGJmYzIifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNDg1NDEyMjQ1LCJleHAiOjE0ODU0MTU4NDUsImF0X2hhc2giOiJMSV9DTWxzeG1lSTdvQm9lSUxoSjZRIiwiYXVkIjoiNDY4MzU1OTM0NzMzLXZqNnRkdDJtazEwZ3R0OHJvZGY2bG84MHM4czdtdTRrLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTEyNjE1NTE5MDY0MTc3ODI0NTgzIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOnRydWUsImF6cCI6IjQ2ODM1NTkzNDczMy12ajZ0ZHQybWsxMGd0dDhyb2RmNmxvODBzOHM3bXU0ay5hcHBzLmdvb2dsZXVzZXJjb250ZW50LmNvbSIsImVtYWlsIjoibWdoYXphbmZhcmFsaWtoYW4wOUBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.Bpa2_zeVebQ7xtKXvuEell50bvUtKOGb5ZertUZGvzGWXnlA-c2kw4Mvko9Xd4JI_R4wbFoyBtrGCiK0jAlJMgaIH8p3wJbzNKPZ-gPFJdX8mv4v42v8-9urGM7rRUCDylz16WEcR1A2qOmEcNCpCf0_FGNpChl8sc8q8zvTnIb_zYYHp_V7ebR2RlUuO2z9G5YzBN3hZDnmen1xLStmNmYKsIiP5ypMqbWaLjnXJjre6bjTuIGymg_phDYDmwWMVTJyx88zmKAfwQTCh2u3qe_fkCDxxm0MO2wC29__q4uc0BfUNdH62GOrNTBJXmPTUZuT1vdUhzz4CLu1KUohWg";
    /*$id_token = $request->get("id_token");*/
    $access_token = $request->get("access_token");

    $token_status = Array();

    $id_status = Array();
    if (!empty($id_token)) {
      // Check that the ID Token is valid.
      try {
        // Client library can verify the ID token.
        $jwt = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token, CLIENT_ID)->getAttributes();
        $gplus_id = $jwt["payload"]["sub"];

        $id_status["valid"] = true;
        $id_status["gplus_id"] = $gplus_id;
        $id_status["message"] = "ID Token is valid.";
      } catch (Google_AuthException $e) {
        $id_status["valid"] = false;
        $id_status["gplus_id"] = NULL;
        $id_status["message"] = "Invalid ID Token.";
      }
      $token_status["id_token_status"] = $id_status;
    }

    $access_status = Array();
    if (!empty($access_token)) {
      $access_status["valid"] = false;
      $access_status["gplus_id"] = NULL;
      // Check that the Access Token is valid.
      $reqUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' .
              $access_token;
      $req = new Google_HttpRequest($reqUrl);

      $tokenInfo = json_decode(
          $client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)
              ->getResponseBody());

      if ($tokenInfo->error) {
        // This is not a valid token.
        $access_status["message"] = "Invalid Access Token.";
      } else if ($tokenInfo->audience != CLIENT_ID) {
        // This is not meant for this app. It is VERY important to check
        // the client ID in order to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.
        $access_status["message"] = "Access Token not meant for this app.";
      } else {
        $access_status["valid"] = true;
        $access_status["gplus_id"] = $tokenInfo->user_id;
        $access_status["message"] = "Access Token is valid.";
      }
      $token_status["access_token_status"] = $access_status;
    }

    return $app->json($token_status, 200);
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Have you tried `composer install` ?

Comment: And have you tried with `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: If having any error then send the error list.

Comment: Also in which directory are you keeping the file?

Comment: @itsazzad yes i have tried them both, all the files are placed in htdocs.

Comment: So far the error is not related to the Google API.
Please follow http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html in a separate project first and after success there try with Google API

Comment: yes i tried in a separate project too.. but its not working... I have been to many websites.. but i am not getting how to make it work.

Comment: What is the version of silex?

Comment: Turn on error reporting and see that the basic installation of silex working or not. Follow silex doc. Otherwise its irrelevant. I have just tested with silex 2.0 and its working so so.

Comment: Even I am working with silex 2.0.. is ithis working fine with you?? Can you suggest me anyother link of the related api for tokenid authentication..??

Comment: If your silex app is ready then you may follow https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started
And as per the question your silex app is not setup correctly. So fix that first.

Comment: I believe your composer installation process failed for Silex. Delete "vendor" folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
composer install (after that run this command)
composer dump-autoload
```

it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

If your Framework don't work after migration.
or see Class 'Silex\Application' not found.
Delete "vendor" folder after composer install.

Working for me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to give a good description of your answer or explanation of how your answer works so that it would be helpful to others.